# Prove $x_n = n^2 \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be defined as $x_n = n^2 \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ How could we show that the sequence is divergent as $\{ x_n\}$ tends to infinity using the definition of the limit?

I tried using the definition of the limit but am getting stuck at the very beginning:  $|n^2 - x| < \epsilon$

Comment: Can you write the definition of what you have to prove : "the sequence $(x_n)$ tends to $+\infty$" ?

Comment: I thought we could argue by contradiction and assume that $x_n$ does converge as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: It could work, but you will only get that the sequence is divergent (you will not know if it tends to $\pm \infty$ or if it has no limit). Whereas using simply the definition, you can prove easily that the sequence diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes you could, but **before** you do that, you must explicitly specify the definition - that is, what TheSilverDoe commented.  I advise: starting with the definition: go for proof by contradiction.  If you still can't solve the problem, **edit** your query to include the definition that you are working with as well as your work, using this definition.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Interesting point, re your 2nd comment.  However, given that the problem is challenging to the OP, and given the problem stated in the query's title, I favor simplicity.

Comment: I edited the question. And I did try already to find a contradiction but i just kept getting stuck at the very beginning.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody actually answered the question using the definition of a limit!

Comment: @Mark, how about now. Look at my answer.

Comment: @DrewBrady Very nice proof, but i dont see how it is using epsilon delta definition of a limit

Comment: @Mark, I am using $\epsilon = 1$, right? There is no $\delta$ in the definition of a limit.

Comment: I have tried to make it yet more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ says the following:

> For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$.

In this case, we say that the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent.

In your case, $x_n=n^2$ and you want to show that $(x_n)$ is **divergent**. So you should not begin with $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ because this sequence has no limit at all!

Instead, what you want to show is that $(x_n)$ does not converge to any real number $x$, which is the "negation" of the definition:

> For every real number $x$, there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that for every positive integer $N$, there exists an $n>N$ such that $|n^2-x|\ge \epsilon$.

Proof. Let $x$ be a real number. We may assume that $x>0$. (The case when $x\le 0$ is an easy exercise.)
Let $M$ be an integer such that $M\le x<M+1$. For any $n$ with $n^2>M+2$
$$
|n^2-x|=n^2-x\ge n^2-(M+1)>1.
$$
If we let $\epsilon=1$, then for every positive integer $N$, we have
$$
|n^2-x|>\epsilon
$$
where $n$ is such that $n^2>\max(M+2,N)+1$ (such $n$ always exists).

Comment: Such a well written proof. Thank you. I understand completely now.

Comment: @Mark: glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to interpret this question. First, we can show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ cannot converge to any real number $x$. From $x_1=1>0$ and $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^2 = \left(1 + \frac1n\right)^2 > 1$$
we conclude by induction that $\{x_n\}$ is a positive, monotone increasing sequence. Hence if the sequence has a limit $x$, then $x$ must be the least upper bound of the set $\{x_n : n\in\mathbb N\}$. In particular we must have $x\geqslant 1$. But if $x=\sup\{x_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, then $$|x_{\lceil x\rceil+1}-x| = \left(\lceil x\rceil+1\right)^2 > 1,$$
and hence $$|x_n-x|>|x_{\lceil x\rceil+1}-x|>1$$
for all $n\geqslant \lceil x\rceil + 1$. Therefore the sequence has no limit.

Alternatively, we may show that the sequence has a limit in the extended real numbers $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. For any positive real number $x$, by similar reasoning as above there exists $N_x$ such that $x_n>x$ for $n\geqslant N$. So by definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. Is there a way to do this using the precise definition of a limit (epsilon delta)?

Comment: Yes: suppose that $x_n$ converges. Then for $n$ large enough, $|x_n - x| \leq \epsilon$, and so $|x_n|$ is eventually bounded for $n$ large enough. On the other hand, $\inf_{m \geq n} x_m$ is an increasing sequence. Contradiction.

Comment: @DrewBrady Is there any way you can show this? I attempted a proof by contradiction but could not figure it out.

Comment: Mark, the point is that a convergent sequence is bounded necessarily. So just note that if $x_n$ converges, then $x_n \leq B^2$ for some $B^2$, but this is a contradiction as soon as $n > B$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall: if $x_n$ converges to a limit $x$, then for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N(\epsilon)$ such that  $|x_n - x| \leq \epsilon$ for $n \geq N(\epsilon)$.

So suppose that $x_n$ converges. Note that then there is $N := N(1)$ such that $x_n \leq x + 1$ for all $n \geq N$. Let $$B^2 = \max\{x_1, \dots, x_N, x + 1\}.$$ Then by construction,
$$
x_n \leq B^2 \qquad \mbox{for all}~n.
$$
But now consider any $n > (B + 1)$. We have $(B+1)^2 < n^2 = x_n^2 \leq B^2$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Is there a reason this was downvoted?